# "react-native run-android" does not open emulator

Tags: react-native

I followed the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#using-a-virtual-device) section in the react-native tutorial.
Installed Marshmallow API Level 23, x86_64 ABI image with a Android 6.0 (Google APIs).

I've ran:

```
react-native run-android
```

Got:

> Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users[My
>   User]\path\to\native\project\node_modules (28ms)

Expected: [Emulator should open](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#running-your-react-native-application)
Actual: Nothing happens

What am I doind wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native run-android` does not open emulator you have to do it manually

`react-native run-ios` is capable to open emulator is mac